# What's the recommended way to read/write a .NET assembly from Java?

Tags: java, clr, assemblies, .net-assembly, cil

It seems like there are plenty of tools to emit .NET assemblies from .NET itself, but there doesn't seem to be a library in the JVM space to do the same.

For instance, the Wikipedia for ASM only mentions:

> ASM is Java-centric at present, and does not currently have a backend
>   that exposes other bytecode implementations (such as .NET bytecode,
>   Python bytecode, etc.).

I can't imagine that this issue hasn't come up before, but I'm unable to find any hints how this has been solved in the past.

Comment: Could you explain why would you want to do that?

Comment: perhaps you can use ikvm.net? You can compile java byte code then use that to transpile it to .net

Comment: @Michael: I'm looking for something with less dependencies. If I require .NET to be available, I could just write C# in the first place, right? :-P

Comment: Well, this allows you to write java and create a .net dll. You can use mono as well, if you are writing on a non-windows platform. I don't think anyone has gone through and created a java jar that just emits CIL. This is really the only information on the subject http://www.ikvm.net/userguide/tutorial.html#Develop+a+.NET+Application+in+Java